# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toarray'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am extracting features out of a text corpus, and I am using a td-fidf vectorizer and truncated singular value decomposition from scikit-learn in order to achieve that. However, since the algorithm I want to try out requires dense matrices and the vectorizer returns sparse matrices I need to convert those matrices to dense arrays. But, whenever I try to convert those arrays I get an error telling me that my numpy array object has no atribute "toarray". What am I doing wrong?

**The function:**

```
def feature_extraction(train,train_test,test_set):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 3,strip_accents = "unicode",analyzer = "word",token_pattern = r'\w{1,}',ngram_range = (1,2))        

    print("fitting Vectorizer")
    vectorizer.fit(train)

    print("transforming text")
    train = vectorizer.transform(train)
    train_test = vectorizer.transform(train_test)
    test_set = vectorizer.transform(test_set)

    print("Dimensionality reduction")
    svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components = 100)
    svd.fit(train)
    train = svd.transform(train)
    train_test = svd.transform(train_test)
    test_set = svd.transform(test_set)

    print("convert to dense array")
    train = train.toarray()
    test_set = test_set.toarray()
    train_test = train_test.toarray()

    print(train.shape)
    return train,train_test,test_set
```

**traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\workspace\final_submission\src\linearSVM.py", line 24, in <module>
    x_train,x_test,test_set = feature_extraction(x_train,x_test,test_set)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\workspace\final_submission\src\Preprocessing.py", line 57, in feature_extraction
    train = train.toarray()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toarray'
```

**Update:**
Willy pointed out that my assumption of the matrix being sparse might be wrong. So I tried feeding my data to my algorithm with dimensionality reduction and it actually worked without any conversion, however when I excluded dimensionality reduction, which gave me around 53k features I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\workspace\final_submission\src\linearSVM.py", line 28, in <module>
    result = bayesian_ridge(x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test,test_set)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\workspace\final_submission\src\Algorithms.py", line 84, in bayesian_ridge
    algo = algo.fit(x_train,y_train[:,i])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\bayes.py", line 136, in fit
    dtype=np.float)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 220, in check_arrays
    raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

Can someone explain this?

**Update2**

As requested, I'll give all the code involved. Since it is scattered over different files I'll just post it in steps. For clarity I'll leave all the module imports out.

This is how I preprocess my code:

```
def regexp(data):
    for row in range(len(data)):
        data[row] = re.sub(r'[\W_]+'," ",data[row])
        return data

def clean_the_text(data):
    alist = []
    data = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
    for j in data:
        j = j.lower()
        alist.append(j.rstrip('\n'))
    alist = " ".join(alist)
    return alist
def loop_data(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i] = clean_the_text(data[i])
    return data  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("loading train")
    train_text = porter_stemmer(loop_data(regexp(list(np.array(p.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"train.csv")))[:,1]))))
    print("loading test_set")
    test_set = porter_stemmer(loop_data(regexp(list(np.array(p.read_csv(os.path.join(dir,"test.csv")))[:,1]))))
```

After splitting my train_set into a x_train and a x_test for cross_validation I transform my data using the feature_extraction function above.

```
x_train,x_test,test_set = feature_extraction(x_train,x_test,test_set)
```

Finally I feed them into my algorithm

```
def bayesian_ridge(x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test,test_set):
    algo = linear_model.BayesianRidge()
    algo = algo.fit(x_train,y_train)
    pred = algo.predict(x_test)
    error = pred - y_test
    result.append(algo.predict(test_set))
    print("Bayes_error: ",cross_val(error))
    return result
```

Comment: If `train` is already an ndarray, then your assumption about it returning a sparse matrix is incorrect.

Comment: You might be right, let me check that.

Comment: Checked it. Going to add an edit to my question right now.

Comment: you should include **all** the code, not just messages. `ndarray` is dense by definition, sparse matrices are represented in different objects, so there is rather an error in your code (which you did not attach)

Comment: Ok, I'll add all the code involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TruncatedSVD.transform` returns an array, not a sparse matrix. In fact, in the present version of scikit-learn, only the vectorizers return sparse matrices.

Comment: @Learner: it's in the [docstring](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html#sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.transform) for that method.